# React forwardref current is always null

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ref

So, I'm trying to implement the react forwardref example for my component, as I want to control a scrollbar inside.

Here's what I have:

```
const MessagesFC = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {       
    return <Flex
        className={"Messages"}
        direction={"Column"}
        ref={ref}>
        {messages}
    </Flex>
});

const scrollDivRef = React.createRef<any>();

React.useEffect(() => {
    scrollDivRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth"})
}, [ scrollDivRef, chatRoom.messages ])
```

Inside my return(), the component is added like this:

```
<MessagesFC 
    ref={scrollDivRef}/>
```

Seems to be setup just like in the example.

However, when executing this code, the scrollDivRef.current is always undefined.

So, where did I go wrong?

Screenshot of my code:

[image]

Comment: Where is useEffect used?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri useEffect is part of the React API.

Comment: Obviously I know that, in your post useEffect is written independenly from MessagesFC.  This is what creates confusion  since hooks cannot be used outside of functional components

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Not my post, and it's not obvious that you know since you're asking where its defined and the answer is in the React API. Anyway, scrollDivRef.current I believe is undefined because the reference only exists inside the forwardRef callback.

Comment: It highly depends on how and where you have used defined the MessagesFC functional component. Please add more code that provides this information

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri It's essentially all inside the parent component right now, what do you need exactly? Then I can provider it. The MessagesFC is defined in the parent like this and also returned from the parents return()

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I added an image of the whole code, I think that is the easiest to comprehend

Comment: Yes, that works, I added an answer for your issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First** of all you must note that in a functional component you must use `useRef` to define ref and not React.createRef since useRef will return you the same ref instance everytime whereas React.createRef will give you a different ref instance

**Second**, MessageFC component needs to be defined outside of the Parent component not inside of its body, otherwise a new instance of it is created again and you will always see the component getting remounted which is why the scrollDivRef inside of useEffect will not give you accurate information

**Third** You don't need to add scrollDivRef as a dependency to useEffect.

```
const MessagesFC = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {       
    return <Flex
        className={"Messages"}
        direction={"Column"}
        ref={ref}>
        {messages}
    </Flex>
});

const Parent = () => {
    const scrollDivRef = React.useRef<any>();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        scrollDivRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth"})
    }, [ chatRoom.messages ]);

    ...
}
```